# Erro no gradle build: "java.exe finished with non-zero exit value 2"

Tags: android, gradle

Estou com esse erro no meu Android Studio, isso acontece quando eu executo uma aplicação que estou desenvolvendo.
Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

[image: Log de build do Gradle]

Segue o meu build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "android.com.br.apptoner"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile files('libs/gson-2.3.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/retrofit-2.0.0.jar')
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0'



    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.1.0'
}
```

Comment: Tente adicionar isso no arquivo build.gradle:  defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}

Comment: Apareceu esse erro depois que eu coloquei o comando que você sugeriu: "Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: retrofit2/BuiltInConverters$BufferingResponseBodyConverter.class"

Comment: Poste o arquivo build.gradle.

Comment: @Geferson postado

Comment: Primeira parte do gradle:
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "android.com.br.apptoner"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

Comment: Substitua essa linha : compile files('libs/gson-2.3.1.jar') por essa 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1' e remova essa compile files('libs/retrofit-2.0.0.jar'), veja se dá certo. Não esqueça de dar um limpar e construir no projeto.

Comment: Onde encontro a opção de "limpar e construir" no android studio?

Comment: É na barra superior o ícone do Build, mas pode usar o atalho Ctrl + F9.

Comment: Relacionado ou não, provavelmente é uma boa ideia instalar o JDK 7, que é a maior versão do Java com suporte do Android.

Comment: Atualizei pro jdk8 achando que poderia ser problemas no java, mas mesmo assim vou tentar novamente o JDK7.

Comment: Já estou com mais de uma semana batendo com erros nesse android studio, saindo de um problema e entrando em outro. Enquanto isso meu projeto parado.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo eu tenho um app ja em uso na play store   e uso essa build.gradle 
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "naovemaocaso.com.br
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 12
        versionName "2.0"

        //para atualizar a versao do app  basta mudar o version code
        //version name não precisa alterar   mas e ele que e exibido na play store
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    compile files('libs/GraphView-4.0.1.jar')
}
```

esse ultimo compile e pra gerar graficos no android...
espero ter ajudado